# Microsoft Azure spark kusto connector -- Is it possible to get files of azure storage out of databricks?

Tags: python-3.x, azure, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-data-explorer

I'm trying to read and write files at azure storage, my attempts until now:

Creating the Spark Session:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext


sparkOptions = {"executor_memory" : "1G","driver_memory": "1G", "max_results_size": "1G"}
conf = pyspark.SparkConf().setAppName(app)
conf = (conf.setMaster("local[*]")
    .set('spark.executor.memory', sparkOptions["executor_memory"])\
    .set('spark.driver.memory', sparkOptions["driver_memory"])\
    .set('spark.driver.maxResultSize', sparkOptions["max_results_size"])\
    .set('spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled', "true")\
    .set('spark.jars.packages', 'com.microsoft.azure.kusto:spark-kusto-connector:1.0.0')\
    .set("fs.azure", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem")\
    .set("fs.azure.account.auth.type", "OAuth")\
    .set("fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider")\
    .set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id", id)\
    .set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret", secret)\
    .set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint", endpoint)\
    .set("fs.azure.createRemoteFileSystemDuringInitialization", "true")
    )

sparkContext = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)
sparkSession = SparkSession(sparkContext)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sparkContext)
```

Trying to read a CSV in azure storage:

```
df = sparkSession.read.option("header", "true").csv("wasbs://container@account.blob.core.windows.net/archive.csv")
df.show()
```

Error:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-975f978e0f66> in <module>()
----> 1 df = sparkSession.read.option("header", "true").csv("wasbs://container@account.blob.core.windows.net/archive.csv")
      2 df.show()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in csv(self, path, schema, sep, encoding, quote, escape, comment, header, inferSchema, ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace, ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace, nullValue, nanValue, positiveInf, negativeInf, dateFormat, timestampFormat, maxColumns, maxCharsPerColumn, maxMalformedLogPerPartition, mode, columnNameOfCorruptRecord, multiLine, charToEscapeQuoteEscaping, samplingRatio, enforceSchema, emptyValue)
    474             path = [path]
    475         if type(path) == list:
--> 476             return self._df(self._jreader.csv(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
    477         elif isinstance(path, RDD):
    478             def func(iterator):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o68.csv.
: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: wasbs
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2660)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1.apply(DataSource.scala:547)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1.apply(DataSource.scala:545)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary(DataSource.scala:545)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:359)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:618)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Trying with abfss:

```
df = sparkSession.read.option("header", "true").csv("abfss://container@account.blob.core.windows.net/archive.csv")
df.show()
```

Error:

```
y4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-02abec06890e> in <module>()
----> 1 df = sparkSession.read.option("header", "true").csv("abfss://container@account.blob.core.windows.net/archive.csv")
      2 df.show()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in csv(self, path, schema, sep, encoding, quote, escape, comment, header, inferSchema, ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace, ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace, nullValue, nanValue, positiveInf, negativeInf, dateFormat, timestampFormat, maxColumns, maxCharsPerColumn, maxMalformedLogPerPartition, mode, columnNameOfCorruptRecord, multiLine, charToEscapeQuoteEscaping, samplingRatio, enforceSchema, emptyValue)
    474             path = [path]
    475         if type(path) == list:
--> 476             return self._df(self._jreader.csv(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
    477         elif isinstance(path, RDD):
    478             def func(iterator):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o104.csv.
: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: abfss
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2660)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1.apply(DataSource.scala:547)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1.apply(DataSource.scala:545)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary(DataSource.scala:545)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:359)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:618)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Searching for examples of utilization of the kusto-spark connector I've only found examples in databricks, utilizing dbutils, I wanna know if it's possible to use the connector out of databricks and what I'm doing wrong in my code, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really about kusto
Are you using Azure databricks? If so simply refer their [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/azure-storage#--mount-azure-blob-storage-containers-to-dbfs).
If not try importing

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-azure</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

If it doesn't help - download the connector code from GitHub and change this dependency 
to 2.7 (the connector uses 3.2)
Btw, don't know if you did or didn't but you have to set key or sas to this container via the spark conf